# IMPORTXML Content is empty

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use the Google Sheets IMPORTXML formula to import the estimated value of a funko pop.

I've tried using different XPATH's, and those (like the title) seem to work fine, but for some reason it doesn't return the value.

Cell F20 URL:   `https://www.hobbydb.com/marketplaces/poppriceguide/catalog_items/iron-man-model-39` 
Cell G20 XPATH I Tried last: `/*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "value", " " ))]`
Formula: `=IMPORTXML(F20;G20)`

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `the price of a funko pop`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the output value you expect?

Comment: of course @Tanaike! There is an "Estimated Value" listed (In the example it says $17.00). So the expected output would be 17.00

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, it seems that at the site of the URL, the value you expect is retrieved by the request with Javascript. By this, the value cannot be retrieved using `IMPORTXML`. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the use of `IMPORTXML` in this situation is **not** possible.

According to the `IMPORTXML` [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en):

> `IMPORTXML` imports data from any of various structured data types including XML, HTML, CSV, TSV, and RSS and ATOM XML feeds.

Therefore, the `=IMPORTXML()` command you are using reads the `HTML` source of the page without any JavaScript code associated with it and **without** executing it - the reason why you are not able to retrieve the wanted data from it.

#### Reference

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en)