# Get the value inside span for XPATH in Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xpath

I am trying to create spreadsheet that pulls the Lexile level of a book from https://hub.lexile.com/ using an IMPORTXML function.
[image]

My table looks like this with the ISBN in the A column and the Lexile level [supposed to] appearing in the B column.

[image]

I used "inspect" to copy the XPATH for the Lexile value and then created this formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://hub.lexile.com/find-a-book/book-details/"&$A2,"/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span/text()")
```

but I get the "Imported content is empty" message from Sheets. Any ideas how to pull the value from the span?
TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IMPORTXML Content is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66501083/importxml-content-is-empty). As seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/gPke5r9) when JavaScript is disabled for the website, no information gets loaded, thus `IMPORTXML` doesn't work.

Comment: @IrvinJayG. - Yep, I think you are correct. Any recommendations for other methods for pulling the value into a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

## SUGGESTION

> To answer your follow-up question @[Teed Ferguson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10719861/teed-ferguson)

***Here are your other options:***

- Use the **API** service from `lexile.com` to request the data from their server. You can use the [**Google Apps Script**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) to request the needed data via an API call and then pass it to your Google spreadsheet file.

> Note: This applies only if `lexile.com` offers an API service to their users. You can reach their [support](https://support.lexile.com/s/contactsupport) to double check on this, as there are no publicly available docs released by `lexile` when searched online.

- Another option is by using **Selenium** & **Python** for a more advanced web-scraping, [see this example](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-selenium-to-web-scrape-with-example-80f9b23a843a). This would also require you to access the [Google Sheet API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) using Python code to be able to pass the scraped data into your spreadsheet file. Please note this is a more tedious task as this requires multiple tools & resources for it to be achieved.

Comment: @TeedFerguson this is to answer your follow-up question.